# How to send response from a Gateway in spring-integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm following the sample below to implement spring-integration gateway.

Issue: Not able to get response on the Gateway which is sent from a service-activator.

1. Gateway reply-channel is "bestQuoteResponseChannel".
2. Service-activator writes to the same channel.

All the custom methods are executed and response is composed but never gets sent out. Any idea what's missing here?
My configuration also has a scatter-gather in the flow.

```
<!--Gateway:-->
<channel id="bestQuoteResponseChannel"/>
<gateway id="loanBrokerGateway"
        default-request-channel="loanRequestsChannel"
        service-interface="org.springframework.integration.samples.loanbroker.LoanBrokerGateway">
    <method name="getBestLoanQuote" reply-channel="bestQuoteResponseChannel">
        <header name="RESPONSE_TYPE" value="BEST"/>
    </method>
</gateway>

<chain input-channel="loanRequestsChannel">
    <header-enricher>
        <header name="creditScore" expression="@creditBureau.getCreditReport(payload).score"/>
    </header-enricher>
    <recipient-list-router apply-sequence="true">
        <recipient selector-expression="headers.creditScore > 800" channel="exclusiveBankChannel"/>
        <recipient selector-expression="headers.creditScore > 750" channel="premiereBankChannel"/>
        <recipient selector-expression="headers.creditScore > 700" channel="qualityBankChannel"/>
        <recipient selector-expression="headers.creditScore > 650" channel="friendlyBankChannel"/>
        <recipient channel="easyBankChannel"/>
    </recipient-list-router>
</chain>

<!-- Messages are sent to the banks via bank channels and will be received and processed by an aggregator -->

<aggregator input-channel="loanQuotesChannel" output-channel="input" method="aggregateQuotes">
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.samples.loanbroker.LoanQuoteAggregator"/>
</aggregator>

<service-activator ref="findBestQuoteService" method="findBestQuote" input-channel="input" output-channel="bestQuoteResponseChannel"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `scatter-gather` in the spring-integration flow before it sends reply to the Gateway. That was somehow was preventing it to send the response to Gateway.

**Changes made:**
I replaced `scatter-gather` component with the `publish-subscribe channel` and `aggregator` combination.
It worked fine after this change.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M1/reference/html/scatter-gather.html#scatter-gather-namespace

Comment: Here is the good link which I referred for the scatter-gather:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M1/reference/html/scatter-gather.html#scatter-gather-namespace

Answer (score 0):

First of all for such a scenario you don't need a `reply-channel` on a gateway and therefore you don't need that `output-channel` on the service activator. All the reply logic should land on the `replyChannel` header which is always populated by the framework when gateway method is called.

It would be great to see what your `findBestQuoteService.findBestQuote` does since the `LoanQuoteAggregator` does everything for us already:

```
/**
 * Aggregates LoanQuote Messages to return a single reply Message.
 *
 * @param quotes list of loan quotes received from upstream lenders
 * @param responseType header that indicates the response type
 * @return the best {@link LoanQuote} if the 'RESPONSE_TYPE' header value is 'BEST' else all quotes
 */
public Object aggregateQuotes(List<LoanQuote> quotes,
        @Header(value="RESPONSE_TYPE", required=false) String responseType) {
    Collections.sort(quotes);
    return ("BEST".equals(responseType)) ? quotes.get(0) : quotes;
}
```

So, what is the point of your custom service thereafter?

Also consider to turn on DEBUG level for the `org.springframework.integration` category to see how your messages are traveling. Possibly we will see some issue in logs, too.

I don't see how your logic could lose a `replyChannel` header, but we need more info to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I'm using aggregator to build the list. Aggregator is then feeding it to the "service-activator" which has custom logic to filter out the best one based on some params. 
How can I pass on the response as the Gateway response?

Comment: OK. That's one point. How about others? Probably DEBUG logs would be really helpful.

Comment: How do I enable debug on the xml to see all the messages? Is that a config?

Comment: Just configure your logging for the `org.springframework.integration` category to log under `DEBUG` level. For example with Log4J 2 it is like this: `<Logger name="org.springframework.integration" level="debug"/>`

Comment: Followed the documentation to create a default-reply-channel on a Gateway from the below link. Channel is of publish-subscribe type. I can also see in logs that a bridge was created to point to that channel. Still not getting the response back from Gateway :(

~log: Adding {bridge:null} as a subscriber to PubSubChannel.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/gateway.html#gateway-default-reply-channel

Comment: I'm using scatter-gather in the process flow. Looks like that is causing it not to work. After I commented out the scatter-gather it's able to send the response to the Gateway.  Does scatter-gather not work in combination with Gateway?

Comment: What Spring Integration version do you use? Show your scatter-gather config, please

Comment: I'm using 5.0.1 version. Using the standard xml based configuration for scatter-gather.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M1/reference/html/scatter-gather.html#scatter-gather-namespace

Comment: Well, let's see if you can upgrade to the latest `5.3.1`: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn ! There were indeed some fixes for Scatter-Gather after that too old `5.0.1`...